# Any negatives of wrapping all code inside Using Webclient?

Tags: c#, webclient

```
using (WebClient client= new WebClient()) 
{
    //specific webclient stuff
}

using (WebClient client= new WebClient()) 
{
    Textbox1.text = "hey";
    //specific webclient stuff
    MessageBox.show("Random");
}
```

Is there any performance difference between those 2?

Is it alright to have not `webclient` related stuff inside a `using webclient`?

Comment: You're not disposing of the `WebClient` until the `using` exits, but other than that, I doubt there'd be any kind of noticeable performance difference.

Comment: @KennethK. I try to keep it as compact as possible, but if it doesn't matter too much I guess I won't worry about ti

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't make too much of a difference for `WebClient`. The trick is to generally try to use an dispose a resource as quickly as possible.

I tend to do this kind of a thing:

```
public static class WebClientEx
{
    public static T Using<T>(this Func<WebClient, T> factory)
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient()
        {
            return factory(wc);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can call code like this:

```
Textbox1.text = "hey";
string text = WebClientEx.Using(wc => wc.DownloadString(@"url"));
MessageBox.show(text);
```

Or even:

```
Func<WebClient, string> fetch = wc => wc.DownloadString(@"url");

Textbox1.text = "hey";
string text = fetch.Using();
MessageBox.show(text);
```

This minimizes the time that the `WebClient` is created and it keeps the code that it is in fairly neat.

Comment: Is it better to have one long open `WebClient` or a bunch of smaller ones?

Comment: @Dgameman1 - That's a matter of opinion, but generally you should keep resource open for the shortest time possible.

Answer (score 2):

On a small scale it doesn't really make much difference, but for best practise I would stick to only instantiating the webclient when you need it and disposing of it as soon as you are done, if you follow best practise for even tiny projects it makes it easier in the long run to follow best practise for large projects.